# google map api not working anymore

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, geolocation

This code was working perfectly until today :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (pos) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        console.log('ok');

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();            
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {
            console.log('callback');
            console.log(status);
        });
    },
    errorGetCurrentPositionCallback,
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 600000});
```

I can see in the console the "ok" message, but not the "callback". There is no error at all and I am using 0% of my quota. Something has changed but not in my code. The console.log is not reached anymore. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function checks if the navigator can find the GPS position (This is purely a device/browser functionality; not a Google service).
But your function does not check the status of geocoder (this is a Google service).

See what your console sais like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function (pos) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
      console.log('Just before geocode is called');
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();            
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {
          console.log('callback of geocoder called');
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log('Status is okay');
          }
          else {
            console.log('Status is not okay, the reason: ' + status);
          }
      });
  },
  errorGetCurrentPositionCallback,
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 600000}
);
```

---

Here is a functioning example

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.45, 4.45);    // set your own default location.  This gets called if the parameters are left blank.
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    }
    function errorGetCurrentPositionCallback() {
      console.log('Your device cannot find your location');
    }
    // initiate Google Maps + request the position of the user.
    function page_loaded() {
      initialize();
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        // success callback
        function (pos) {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
          var accuracy = pos.coords.accuracy;
          map.setCenter(latlng);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map, 
            title: "You are here! (at least within a " + accuracy + " meter radius)"
          });
          console.log('Just before geocode is called');
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();            
          geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {
            console.log('callback of geocoder called');
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              console.log('Status is okay; you have the address of this location');
              // 
            }
            else {
              console.log('Status is not okay, the reason: ' + status);
            }
          });
        },
        errorGetCurrentPositionCallback,
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 600000}
      );
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', page_loaded);
</script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it's the same code "except checking status" that I has omitted on purpose (not useful for the example). The problem is that the line "console.log('callback called')" is not reached. So it's useless to check status after. Something is wrong but it's not in the code. Do you have an idea ? is it possible to have the source code of the api ?

Comment: I should check it more thoroughly.  By the way, do you log something in errorGetCurrentPositionCallback ?  Anything interesting there?

Comment: No I have nothing neither in the errorGetCurrentPositionCallback. I thing the callback is not fired in the google code. But why ?

Comment: I added a functioning example

Comment: I found the error. I have overridden the eval function and google is using it. So now it's working again. Thanks